# Groovy class with read-only logical property?

Tags: properties, groovy, javabeans, readonly

I have the following class in which I'd like to have the `isDefault()` method. However, when I try to compile it, I get an error that there is NO `setDefault()` method. I realize I could add a `setDefault()` method and make it private, but it seems like there should be a more elegant solution than that.

Any ideas?

```
class LdapConfig {

    public static final String DEFAULT_URL = 'ldap://localhost:389'

    String url = DEFAULT_URL

    public boolean isDefault() {
        if (url == DEFAULT_URL) {
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could there be some other code that's trying to set the `default` property a LdapConfig? This code [seems to work fine](http://ideone.com/p5jLp)

Comment: Your code worked in my groovy 2.0. What's your version?